# How can I store all the dynamic values and attribute labels in a state in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-typescript

I am using react js. I have an attributes array of objects on my single product page and I am displaying the array of objects into the UI. The UI look like this:

[image]

**I am trying to get the values of the selected attributes,** I have set onClick handler to get the value and label but I am only getting the value that is removed after clicking on the second attribute which I don't want. **I want to store all the values and attribute labels in a state.** The attributes are dynamic sometimes it will be 2 or more or none.

This is the code for dynamic attributes.

```
{product?.attributes.map(attr => {
        return <div onClick={e => handleAttribute(e.target)} className=" mr-6 items-center">
            <span className="mr-3"><b>{attr.label}</b></span><br />
            <div className="relative">
                <select className="rounded appearance-none border border-gray-200 py-2 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 text-base pl-3 pr-10">
                    {attr?.selected.map(select => {
                        return <option>{select.label}</option>
                    })}

                </select>
    })}
```

This is the function but I am confused about how can I get the values and also label for each attributes and it will store in a state.

```
   const handleAttribute = (e) => {
        console.log(e, 'attr');

    }
```

**My expected output is something like this:**

```
[
{label: colors, selected: Black},
{label: Size, selected: M}
]
```

The attributes database look like this:

```
   {
            attributes: [{
                label: "colors",
                selected: [{
                    label: "Black",
                    value: "Black"
                },
                {
                    label: 'Green',
                    value: 'Green'
                }]


            },
            {
                label: "size",
                selected: [{
                    label: "M",
                    value: "M"
                },
                {
                    label: 'S',
                    value: 'S'
                }]
            }
        ]
            
        }
```

Comment: You should put an `onChange` handler on the <select> instead. By also giving it a `name` attribute, you can now update your state object/array using `e.target.name` and `e.target.value`. The attribute state will look like `{ colors: "Green", size: "S" }` and that is your basis for creating a controlled select that will update the state.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select onChange((e) => handleAttribute(e))>
   { attr?.selected.map(select => {
            return <option value={select.value}>{select.label}</option>
   })}
</select>

const handleAttribute = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

Hope this helps basically call `onChange` in select and pass the value into the options

Then in the `handleAttribute` method use `e.target.value` to get the value of the *selected option*